# PowerShell script to write a printer name

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell script. This:

```
Get-Printer | ft name,portname,location | Export-Csv c:\intel\intvprint2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But it isn't any good :( I made the script, but the result is file error data.

This it makes:

```
"ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd","pageHeaderEntry","pageFooterEntry","autosizeInfo","shapeInfo","groupingEntry"
"033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280",,,,"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo",
"9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,
```

But now see this:

```
Get-Printer | ft name,portname,location

name                          portname               location
----                          --------               --------
9620HP2055DN                  172.17.252.130         loc1
9590HP2055DN                  172.17.239.45          loc2
```

Why isn't the script good?

Comment: Are you using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)? The original was close to incomprehensible.

Comment: (This question was on the [HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) today.)

Comment: Here is [a list of aliases](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) in PowerShell (for a particular version). Alias 'ft' is for cmdlet *[Format-Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table)*.

Comment: What version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 5):

`ft` is an alias for [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), which is meant to output the data pretty in a terminal. You want to use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (alias *select*) instead.

```
Get-Printer | select name,portname,location | Export-Csv c:\intel\intvprint2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```